# Cauchy sequence in $L^p$, existence of a set with finite measure, and integral is less than epsilon over the complement

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The setting is as follows, for each $f\in L^p$, define a set function $\lambda_f$ on $\mathcal{A}$ by $$\lambda_f(E)=\left(\int_E |f|^p d\mu\right)^{1/p}=\|f\cdot I_E\|_p.$$

Let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^p$. Show that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a set $E\in\mathcal{A}$ (depending on $\epsilon$) with $\mu (E)<\infty$ such that for all $F\in\mathcal{A}$ with $F\subseteq E^c$, we have $\lambda_{f_n} (F)<\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I tried proving by contradiction: Suppose to the contrary for all $E\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$, $\exists F\in\mathcal{A}$ with $F\subseteq E^c$ but $\lambda_{f_n}(F)\geq\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Intuitively, I see that that may be a problem as $\mu(E)$ gets larger, $\lambda_{f_n}(F)$ should tend towards zero? However I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

Thanks for any help.

Note: I set a bounty to attract more answers, so that I can choose one that I can understand. Having some problems with understanding this one.

Comment: Maybe the fact that $L^p$ is a complete normed space could help you.

Comment: $f_n$ is Cauchy, so it is bounded in $L^p$. Then it is uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f \in L^p$ and $\epsilon>0,$ then there is a simple function $s, 0\le s \le |f|^p,$ such that $\int_X(|f|^p-s) < \epsilon.$ Now $s\in L^1,$ so no nonzero value of $s$ can be taken on a set of infinite measure. Because $s$ has only finitely many values, the set $E=\{s>0\}$ has finite measure. Thus

$$\int_{E^c}|f|^p = \int_{E^c}(|f|^p-s)+ \int_{E^c}s \le \int_{X}(|f|^p-s)+ 0 < \epsilon.$$

Now suppose $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^p$ and $\epsilon >0.$ Then we can choose $N$ such that $\int_X|f_n-f_N|^p <\epsilon/2^p$ for $n>N.$ Because $|f_1|^p+ \cdots +|f_N|^p \in L^1,$ from the above we can find $E$ such that $\mu(E) <\infty$ and

$$\int_{E^c}(|f_1|^p+ \cdots +|f_N|^p) < \epsilon/2^p.$$

That handles $n=1,\dots , N.$ Suppose $n>N.$ Using $(a+b)^p \le 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$ for $a,b\ge 0,$ we have

$$\int_{E^c}|f_n|^p \le 2^{p-1}(\int_{E^c}|f_n-f_N|^p +\int_{E^c}|f_N|^p) \le 2^{p-1}(\int_{X}|f_n-f_N|^p + \epsilon/2^p) < \epsilon.$$

Above I was assuming $1\le p < \infty,$ but I used no properties of $L^p$ as a normed linear space. The only place I used this restriction was the inequality $(a+b)^p \le 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p).$ But for $0<p <1$ we have $(a+b)^p \le a^p+b^p.$ So actually the above works for the full range $0<p<\infty.$

Comment: I just re-read your proof, and it is really amazing. How did you intuitively arrive at your proof? I can understand your proof, but don't know the idea behind how to approach such questions myself..

Comment: The first paragraph was about proving the result for one function. It's easy to do this for simple functions. And simple functions are often "dense" in measure theory situations, and that was the case here. Moral: Try it for easy things, then see if that is enough. It often is.

Comment: Note I was avoiding the $L^p$ norm because it just seemed to get in the way. So I never took $p$th roots. The rest of it isn't as "rabbit out of hat" as it might appear. Sometimes proofs are a little too polished and rereading this I think it might be the case here. We have $N$ such that $\int|f_n-f_N|^p <\epsilon, n> N.$ That's really the end of the proof! Why? Because we have no trouble finding $E$ for the first $N$ of these guys. That $E$ works for the whole mess of them because they are so close to $f_N$ in the sense above.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by Svetoslav, the key word here is "uniform integrability".

First observe that the result holds true if you take just one function $f$ instead of a sequence (or if you prefer, when your sequence $(f_n)$ is constant). 
This is not completely trivial if you do not want to use any theorem. For every $k\in\mathbb N$, set $E_k:=\{ 1/k\leq \vert f\vert\leq k\}$. The sequence $(E_k)$ is increasing, and the complement of $E_\infty:=\bigcup_k E_k$ is equal to $\{ f=0\}\cup\{ \vert f\vert=\infty\}$. Since $\vert f(x)\vert<\infty$ almost everywhere (because $f\in L^p$), it follows that $\int_{E_\infty^c} \vert f\vert^p=0$. Now, consider the *finite* measure $\mu_f$ defined by $\mu_f(A):=\int_A \vert f\vert^p$. Since $\mu_f$ is finite and $(E_k)$ is increasing, $\mu_f(E_k^c)\to \mu_f(E_\infty^c)=0$. So one can find $k$ such that $\mu_f(E_k^c)<\varepsilon^p$, *i.e.* $\lambda_f(E_k^c)<\varepsilon$. Finally, $E_k$ has finite $\mu$-measure because $\vert f\vert\geq 1/k$ on $E_k$ and $f\in L^p$ (formally, apply Markov's inequality to $\vert f\vert^p$). So you can take $E:=E_k$ for this suitably chosen $k$.

From the "one function case", it follows easily that one can find a suitable set $E$ for any *finite* family of functions $f_1,\dots ,f_N$.

Now, let us come back to our Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$, and assume that the result does not hold true for some $\varepsilon >0$. By the previous remark, this means that for any set $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$, one can find *arbitrarily large* $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\lambda_{f_n}(E^c)\geq\varepsilon)$.

Since $(f_n)$ is Cauchy, one can find $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\Vert f_n-f_N\Vert_p<\varepsilon/2$ for all $n\geq N$; then a set $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ such that $\lambda_{f_N}(E^c)<\varepsilon/2$ (by the "one function case"); and then $n\geq N$ such that $\lambda_{f_n}(E^c)\geq\varepsilon$. But this is a contradiction since, by Minkowski's inequality, we have 
$$\lambda_{f_n}(E^c)\leq \lambda_{f_n-f_N}(E^c)+\lambda_{f_N}(E^c)\leq \Vert f_n-f_N\Vert_p+\lambda_{f_N}(E^c)<\varepsilon\, . $$

Comment: Thanks! Regarding "This is not completely trivial if you do not want to use any theorem." in the one function case, what possible theorem could we use instead?

Comment: In fact, I had something in mind which was completely irrelevant...

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer. However, I don't really understand your solution completely...

Comment: Tell me what is unclear.

Comment: May I ask what is the main purpose of introducing a new measure $\mu$? Also, I am a bit lost on the part of formally applying Markov's inequality to $|f|^p$.

Comment: The point is that the new measure is finite, so the measure of the intersection of a decreasing sequence of the sets is the limit of the measures. As for your second question, Markov's inequality gives you that $\mu(E_k)\leq k^p \int \vert f\vert^pd\mu<\infty$.